# Ruby with LDAP or AD

Tags: ruby, ldap

Is there a way of deciding and confirming with facts regarding, which is better and easier to integrate with Ruby. LDAP or ActiveDirectory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveDirectory is an implementation of the LDAP.  You can use the [RubyLDAP](http://ruby-ldap.sourceforge.net/) gem to integrate with AD.  I am currently using this gem to connect from a RHEL server to a Windows Domain Controller.

```
gem install ruby-ldap
```

Comment: Hi jamin, I am using ruby-ldap and met an issue in rails3 app, can you  please take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979920/ruby-ldap-gem-not-work-in-rails3-app-but-work-in-rails-console

Answer (score 4):

I use the [net-ldap](http://net-ldap.rubyforge.org/) gem to authenticate and query the ActiveDirectory server at work. It works well. Here's some sample code for verifying a user's login credentials and getting their full name.

```
def name_for_login( email, password )
  email = email[/\A\w+/].downcase  # Throw out the domain, if it was there
  email << "@mycompany.com"        # I only check people in my company
  ldap = Net::LDAP.new(
    host: 'ldap.mycompany.com',    # Thankfully this is a standard name
    auth: { method: :simple, email: email, password:password }
  )
  if ldap.bind
    # Yay, the login credentials were valid!
    # Get the user's full name and return it
    ldap.search(
      base:         "OU=Users,OU=Accounts,DC=mycompany,DC=com",
      filter:       Net::LDAP::Filter.eq( "mail", email ),
      attributes:   %w[ displayName ],
      return_result:true
    ).first.displayName.first
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The LDAP bindings for Ruby are pretty decent -- not exactly beautiful, but they work well. And, of course, you can access ActiveDirectory *as* an LDAP server. I have never tried any ActiveDirectory bindings for Ruby.