# ruby-ldap gem not work in rails3 app, but work in rails console

Tags: ldap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to build a rails3 website authed with LDAP, so I chose ruby-ldap gem (not net/ldap) which we used in our old rails2 apps and works very well.

But I keep on getting weird error in rails3 app, See the codes below:

```
require 'ldap'
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index  
    begin
      @test = LDAP::Conn.new('10.72.64.11', 389)
    rescue LDAP::Error
      p LDAP::Error
    end  
    render :text => "ok"
  end
end
```

welcome#index is my root route. Most time, the app crashes when going to LDAP::Conn.new('10.72.64.11', 389), even I tried to use "pry" to debug and track, throwing

```
[1]    24797 trace trap  rails s
```

and the WEBrick server will be terminated right that time.

Sometimes it throws another type error when I use "pry" to step, 
`#<NameError: uninitialized constant WelcomeController::LDAP>`

While try it in the console, everything goes well.

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > require 'ldap'
 => true 
1.9.3-p194 :002 > @test = LDAP::Conn.new('10.72.64.11', 389)
 => #<LDAP::Conn:0x00000101289568> 
1.9.3-p194 :003 >
```

Can you guide me out of this crazy stuff? I am using ruby 1.9.3p194 and rails 3.2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few months later, I kind of figure out what the problem is...

The ruby-ldap gem has problem on running on the rails default server: Webrick.

Try Pow or Passenger, it works perfect!

After reading this page: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/62920

I tried moving the require 'ldap' from the controller or model file, and into the very top line of my environment file (xxxlocal.rb)

After I did that, I was able to run it ok in webrick also.