# Use Ruby Extension (.bundle) in Rails Applications

Tags: objective-c, c, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a built a Ruby Extension for C/Objective-C and now would like to use it in a Ruby on Rails web application but everytime I try to require it, WEBrick crashes!  What I have is:

1. I have a Ruby Class: MyRubyObject which is tied to a C class (MyExtension).
2. MyRubyObject has been defined with one method: myRubyMethod which  is tied to a function in my C class, MyExtension: myextensionmethod which just returns a string.
3. myextensionmethod essentailly calls another library which performs a load of work (multiple threads and what not) but finally returns a string
4. after compiling everything I get a MyRubyObject.bundle file.  Using IRB, I can:

   require './MyRubyObject'
   p = MyRubyObject.new
   p.myRubyMethod
   => "Result!"
5. This all works absolutely fine and now I want to use it in a RoR app
6. I put the MyRubyObject.bundle in lib in my RoR app and then from a controller class I do a require ./lib/MyRubyObject.bundle and WEBrick crashes!!!!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Cheers

Comment: How does webrick crash exactly?

Comment: Web brick boosts as normal and then when I visit the page which loads my controller I just get this on the output: 
    [1]    3316 trace trap  rails s

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution where from here: [ruby-ldap gem not work in rails3 app, but work in rails console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979920/ruby-ldap-gem-not-work-in-rails3-app-but-work-in-rails-console) whereby I

- Put a 'require File.expand_path('../../lib/MyRubyObject',  __FILE__)' in config/environment.rb file (after 'require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)')
- Then in my controller file I just put a require 'MyRubyObject' and was then able to instantiate normally: p = MyRubyObject.new ...

So I presume this was a related issue to WEBrick loading things in an incorrect order based upon the above link but I will keep an eye on this as we'll move servers most likely and this issue may pop it's ugly head up again!

Hope this helps others!
Thanks