# net-ldap credentials error due to simple vs generic method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to use net-ldap to query our ldap server.  I can authenticate through adauth so the ldap server is responding.

I switched from activeldap to net-ldap because I couldn't get a query working with activeldap. I could not get a connection for querying with net-ldap either. I finally traced it to my ldap server apparently wanting a method of 'generic'. However, when I change the settings for net-ldap from simple to generic, I get an error.

I used the ldp.exe tool from microsoft to test my ldap connections separately from the rails app.

I have the following gems installed.

```
gem 'adauth'                        # for active directory/rails integration
gem 'activeldap'                    # required with adauth to provide the active directory connection
gem 'net-ldap'
```

The index method in my observations controller has the following (Some info is xxx'd out)

```
  require 'rubygems'
    require 'net/ldap'
    ldap = Net::LDAP.new :host => '10.0.0.22',
                         :port => 389,
                         :base => "dc=xxxxx,dc=com",
                         :auth => {
                             :method => :simple,
                             :username => 'xxxxxx',
                             :bind_dn => "uid=xxxxx,ou='xxxxx',dc=xxxx,dc=com",
                             :password => 'xxxxx'
                         }

    filter = Net::LDAP::Filter.eq( "cn", "George*" )
    treebase = "dc=xxxxx,dc=com"

    ldap.search( :base => treebase, :filter => filter ) do |entry|
      puts "DN: #{entry.dn}"
      entry.each do |attribute, values|
        puts "   #{attribute}:"
        values.each do |value|
          puts "      --->#{value}"
        end
      end
    end

    p ldap.get_operation_result
```

when I go to the index, I have ldap.get_operation_result displayed which shows

```
<OpenStruct extended_response=nil, code=49, error_message="80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1\u0000", matched_dn="", message="Invalid Credentials">
```

52e says that the password is bad.

If I change the method to generic, I get

```
Net::LDAP::AuthMethodUnsupportedError in ObservationsController#index
Unsupported auth method (generic)

Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/employee_observations

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/observations_controller.rb:61:in `index'
```

If I test using ldp.exe with the same credentials I'm using above using generic, I get

```
res = ldap_bind_s(ld, NULL, &NtAuthIdentity, 1158); // v.3
    {NtAuthIdentity: User='railsauthentication'; Pwd= <unavailable>; domain = 'ccttapes1.com'.}
Authenticated as dn:'railsauthentication'.
```

If I switch to simple, I get a failure to bind of

```
res = ldap_simple_bind_s(ld, 'railsauthentication', <unavailable>); // v.3
Error <49>: ldap_simple_bind_s() failed: Invalid Credentials
Server error: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
```

Apparently my ldap server is looking for the method being generic but net-ldap will not allow me to set the method to generic

===========================  update 4 29 ===================================

I changed the ldap settings to

```
ldap = Net::LDAP.new :host => '10.0.0.23',
                     :port => 389,
                     :base => "dc=cct,dc=com",
                     :auth  => { :username => "railsauthentication",
                                 :password => "xxxxxx" }

if ldap.blank?
  $temp2 = 'blank'
end
```

I now get the following for p ldap.get_operation_result

```
<OpenStruct code=0, message="Success">
```

That would seem to indicate that i am authenticating OK based on my limited familiarity with ldap.

However, if I try to add the following to the controller, I get an error

```
if ldap.bind
  # authentication succeeded
else
  # authentication failed
end
```

the error is

```
Net::LDAP::AuthMethodUnsupportedError in ObservationsController#index
Unsupported auth method ()

Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/employee_observations

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/observations_controller.rb:53:in `index'
```

Line 53 is the if ldap.bind

I am confused as to if I am really establishing a connection or not.

Comment: Have you tried authenticating without the `bind_dn` in the auth hash?

Comment: @treiff - That did seem to work. I added an update to my original question. However, I still am having issues as to actually getting ldap to query.

Comment: You are still going to need a auth method in the hash, so your going to want to have `:method => :simple` inside the auth hash.  That error is indicating you need to include a auth method.

Comment: I made a bad assumption when I saw port 389 open on our primary and secondary domain controllers. The lightweight directory system was no running on either server. I am installing it now on our web server and will see if that fixes the problem. I made the assumption that adauth was authenticating through LDAP but I think I was wrong. I believe that was probably going straight to active directory.   I'll see what happens after the LDS is installed on the web server.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the DN in your bind operation is incorrect. The error message with the matched DN set to the empty string indicates that the server likely could not parse the DN. Are you sure that you are encoding the DN properly at the following line:

```
:bind_dn => "uid=xxxxx,ou='xxxxx',dc=xxxx,dc=com",
```

Note that according to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366092(v=vs.85).aspx) `ldap_simple_bind_s` can only take regular a LDAP distinguished name, but `ldap_bind_s` can take a user name as well. It is no surprise that your last example with the DN parameter set to `railsauthentication` fails.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was that I was just using the login name, not the fully qualified name. I got the clue at [Ruby with LDAP or AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864743/ruby-with-ldap-or-ad)

`:username => 'xxxxxx',` should be `:username => 'xxxxxx@mycompany.com',`

I also used the domain\user format for my bind statement as

```
 ldap.bind(:method=>:simple, :dn => 'cn=companydomain\user', :password => 'xxxxxx')
```

That seems to be getting me a reliable connection for querying directly to active directory